# vars() in Python giving different output

Tags: python, string, names, variables

When I run this code:

```
a = '1'
vars()['a'] = '2'
print a
```

I get the following output:

```
2
```

But when I run this code:

```
def bar():
    a = '1'
    vars()['a'] = '2'
    print a

bar()
```

I get the following output:

```
1
```

Now my question is why does that happen and how can I make the second case give me the same solution as the first case.

Edit:

Couldn't really find a solution but I found a small hack around it... Though I'll rather not use exec:

```
def bar():
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    exec a+"="+b
    print a

bar()
```

Which gets me the outcome:

```
b
```

If anyone can find a better solution then it would be great. I'm not setting any global variables this way or doing anything crazy so don't worry about that.

Comment: I believe the class makes no difference - it's a matter of local versus global scope.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to set a global var this way from within a function, you might be doing something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like new style classes override the default `__dict__` behavior and thus break this useage of `vars()`.  Not certain why it would impact old style classes, but it might be related.

From docs (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars):

---

`vars([object])`
Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.

Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable `__dict__` attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their `__dict__` attributes (for example, new-style classes use a dictproxy to prevent direct dictionary updates).

Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored.

---

Could you perhaps comment on why `self. = val` or `setattr(self, 'x', val)` won't work for your class case?

Comment: This part of the docs seems to be the key: "Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored."  I.e., you're not supposed to modify whatever vars() returns.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with class since I can remove the class part and still have the same issue. I believe the problem lies within the function. I have tried the self. = val and setattr(self, 'x', val) but still got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment to the result of `vars()` is not defined.  So it might give different results in different scenarios and/or python versions and/or implementations.  Though it might sound appalling to be able to change local variables using this way (I tried using it for regex groupdict results once), this is highly unportable and might break any time.